# How to handle property sheet from customized editor in eclipse plugin development?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have to bind my editor widget objects in property sheet.So that i can the property of my widget from property view.
Please help me on this, if possible provide me some code snippets.

Comment: Just completed my answer about the `Selection` mechanism, which should be valid for `Editor` as well as `View`.

Answer (score 9):

You have a good example in the [Getting started with Properties](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2007/10/08/getting-started-with-properties/)

> Using the Properties view is simple enough.
>   Since it shows properties for the selected object, **the first step to using it is to make sure that the workbench selection service knows about the object selected in your view**. There’s an entire Eclipse Corner article written on the subject of the selection service

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());

    getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);

    viewer.setInput(getViewSite());
}
```

> Once you have your view contributing to the workbench selection, you need to make sure that the objects that your view is selecting contribute properties

(extract)

```
public class Person implements IPropertySource {
    private String name;
    private Object street;
    private Object city;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.street = "";
        this.city = "";
    }

    public Object getEditableValue() {
        return this;
    }

    public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
        return new IPropertyDescriptor[] {
                new TextPropertyDescriptor("name", "Name"),
                new TextPropertyDescriptor("street", "Street"),
                new TextPropertyDescriptor("city", "City")
        };
    }
```

> I indicated earlier that this solution is “not necessarily [the] most correct”. This is because, for this to work, my domain object needs to know about the very view-centric (and Eclipse-centric) notion of being a property source; in short, there is a tight-coupling between the model and view and this not a good thing™.

Using adapter is a better approach, as [described in this article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53882.rhtml):
Person should implement `IAdaptable`.

---

See also this recent article on [how to create a custom property view](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/05/creating-custom-property-view.html)

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_hsp14iFkRLs/Sg28gW12WnI/AAAAAAAADk4/Y_bxy5lHIvI/s320/PinActionRemoved.png]

> how to hack the Properties View to listen only to a specific view.
>
> The `isImportant()` method is the one which decides whether to create an IPage for the specific IWorkbenchPart or not.
>   The idea is to override that method and return false for all the `workbenchPart` that we are not interested in. Lets create the view first:

```
<view
            class="com.eclipse_tips.views.CustomPropertiesView"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            id="com.eclipse-tips.views.customePropertiesView"
            name="My Properties View">
</view>
```

The `CustomPropertiesView` should extend `PropertySheet` and override the `isImportant()`:

```
public class CustomPropertiesView extends PropertySheet {

 @Override
 protected boolean isImportant(IWorkbenchPart part) {
  if (part.getSite().getId().equals(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER))
   return true;
  return false;
 }
}
```

> In this case, I'm making the view only to respond to Project Explorer and ignore other views

[image: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_hsp14iFkRLs/Sg28Nwe3QSI/AAAAAAAADko/DqnVd7obB1Y/s320/CustomPropertiesProjectExplore.png]

---

According to [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg61831.html), the same principle should be valid for an Editor instead of a View.

> The property sheet listens to the workbench page selection provider.
>   The **selection provider depends on what viewer/editor is active**.
>   **Each editor/viewer provides their own selection provider to use when that editor/viewer is active**.
>   This way the property sheet doesn't care who is active, it just listens to the selection provider.
>   That way depending upon the view, a different set of properties are displayed.
>   For example, the `Navigator` view provides `IResource` selections, so the property sheet then displays `IResource` properties when the Navigator is active.

The Workbench Selection  mechanism is illustrated in [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html)

> The `ISelectionListener` is a simple interface with just one method.
>   A typical implementation looks like this:

```
private ISelectionListener mylistener = new ISelectionListener() {
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcepart, ISelection selection) {
    if (sourcepart != MyView.this &&                               // 1
        selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {               // 2
        doSomething(((IStructuredSelection) selection).toList());  // 3
        }
    }
};
```

> Depending on your requirements your listener implementation probably needs to deal with the following issues as shown in the code snippet above:
>
> - In case we also provide selections (e.g. **a view or editor**) we should exclude our own selection events from processing. This avoids unexpected results when the user selects elements within our part (1).
> - Check whether we can handle this kind of selection (2).
> - Get the selected content from the selection and process it (3).

[image: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/images/diagram1.gif]

Comment: Thanks Vonc.Here you have given code snippets for view.In my case iam using editor 
eg: SampleEditor(My editor) extends EditorPart, How can we add this SelectionProvider for this editor.Do you have any samples for editor part.