# Properties View and Editors

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Hi anyone can explain me how can i let my editor contribute to the Properties View in Eclipse.
The following links explain things in detail but they do not tell how can i register project explorer view or my own editor to the properties view.

- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html
- [How to handle property sheet from customized editor in eclipse plugin development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761219/how-to-handle-property-sheet-from-customized-editor-in-eclipse-plugin-developmen)

Answer (score 1):

The page on eclipse has a [link to an older tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Properties-View/properties-view.html). They explain it there:

> Every workbench part has a `IWorkbenchPartSite`, and one can set the selection provider for this site. When I created our sample view, I instantiated a `ListViewer`, which implements `ISelectionProvider`. I pass this `ListViewer` to the `IWorkbenchPartSite` object via `setSelectionProvider`. **This enables the property view to be informed of selection changes** in our list when our view is the active workbench part.

The view shows properties of a selection, it listens to all selection providers. You don't have to register your view to a *selection receiver*.

Comment: Hi, is the IPropertySource class still the way to do it. I'm having issues as my dev environment can't find that class and I don't know if that's still the way to do it?