# How make that view will display data about selected object in Eclipse platform?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have some (custom) view on may perspective.

I want this view to display data about some selected entity in the other view in the same perspective?

Moreover, another objects are also views.

I.e. I have multiple views of some type (I don't yet know how to implement this, probably I will have single view which allow multiple instances; so I will have multiple instances of the same view).

Let call this "Instance view".

Also I have another singleton view, which we will call "Properties view".

So I want to make so that if user selected one of instance views, then the content of properties view reflect the appropriate instance.

Please hint how to accomplish thos.

Comment: Can you clarify a little how the logic works? It's confusing

Comment: Eclipse has a standard Properties View which you can set up to work with your views see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761219/how-to-handle-property-sheet-from-customized-editor-in-eclipse-plugin-developmen)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your architecture, usually you should use selection listeners, observers or whatever similar patterns you prefer. I think, your questions are answered in [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html).