# Attaching Properties view to a custom XML Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a custom editor in eclipse plugin which shows a XML in Tree-Table(TreeViewer) format with couple of its attributes. For showing remaining attributes I am trying to tie it up with "Properties View", but not really able to make progress on it.

I went through similar question on SO like
[How to handle property sheet from customized editor in eclipse plugin development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761219/how-to-handle-property-sheet-from-customized-editor-in-eclipse-plugin-developmen?lq=1) where it talk about make your viewer contribute to workbench selection and implementing an IPropertySource on object which is selected in editor.

In my case I am directly setting an document object in treeviewer input like below.

```
IFileEditorInput editorInput = (IFileEditorInput) getEditorInput();
IFile inputIFile = editorInput.getFile();
File f = new File(inputIFile.getLocation().toString());
try {
    doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(f);
    } 
    catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
//setting root element of doc as input
treeViewer.setInput(doc.getDocumentElement());
```

Now on what object should I implement an IPropertySource interface to contribute properties?

Let me know if I am going in right direction or missing something or doing it completely wrong.

Hope this make sense !!

Comment: What are you setting as the selection provider for the editor?

Comment: I am setting treeViewer as the selection provider - 'getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your selection provider fires a selection changed event the properties page will look at the new selection. If you are using a tree viewer as the provider the selection will be the current object from your tree content provider.

The properties view will try to get an `IPropertySourceProvider` from the selection. Your object can implement `IPropertySourceProvider` directly, or provide it view the `IAdaptable` interface or by using `IAdapterFactory`.

Once the view has the `IPropertySourceProvier` it will call the `getPropertySource` method. Your code must return an `IPropertySource` object - it is up to you to write this class.

Comment: In this case the current object in treeViewer will be an dom node so how should I implement an IPropertySourceProvider on it ?

Comment: You might be able to do something with an `IAdapterFactory` but most likely you will have to change your content provider to provide an object that wraps to DOM node so you can add the code there.

Comment: thanks!! I was able to make it work using IAdapterFactory.